# How to call many shell functions from sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, alias, function

I have a huge alias file sourced by `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` which contains both simple aliases and more functions for more complex stuff:

```bsh
# example aliases
alias "sudo=sudo "
alias "testalias=echo 'Aliases work as expected'"

# example function
testfunction(){
    echo "Function $1 works as expected"
}
```

This is what happens if I run these commands with or without `sudo`:

```bsh
> testalias
Aliases work as expected

> testfunction "test"
Function test works as expected

> sudo testalias
Aliases work as expected

> sudo testfunction "test"
sudo: testfunction: command not found
```

I've seen no difference either with

- `export -f testfunction && sudo -E testfunction "test"`
- `alias "testfunction-alias=testfunction" && sudo -E testfunction-alias "test"`

How can I call functions from `sudo` as I am already doing with aliases?
Possibly without exporting/creating an alias for each one of them, as they are numerous.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` runs commands, it cannot run aliases or functions. Aliases are a feature of your shell. So, in order to run aliases you first need to launch the root shell.

Comment: I can already launch aliases, are you saying it's not possible to launch shell functions?

Comment: I'm not sure how aliases work for you, they should **not**.